# Moment of Inertia of a Lamina Around the Center of Mass

Tags: plane-geometry, multiple-integral

I have a two-dimensional lamina in the $xy$-plane, and I need to calculate the moment of inertia around the center of mass.
I know that the moment of inertia around the $x$-axis is $I_x = \int\int y^2 \delta(x,y) \mathrm{d}A$ and $I_y = \int\int x^2 \delta(x,y) \mathrm{d}A$ for the $y$-axis, but I'm not sure how to apply that to / find the formula for the vertical axis going through the center of mass...

Thank you in advance

Comment: The moment of inertia about the vertical ($z$) axis can be expressed as a scalar.  It is simply $I_z = \iint (x^2 + y^2)\ dm$, where $x$ and $y$ are measured from the center of mass.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork so if our center of mass is (x,y) our $I_z = \int_{a_1-x}^{a_2-x} \int_{b_1-y}^{b_2-y} (x^2+y^2) dydx$, right?

Comment: Well... it all depends upon the *shape* of the region.

Answer (score 2):

Not a full answer (so please don't downvote), but this figure should help.  The black arrow is the $z$ axis through the center of mass, and the blue arrow represents $r$.  Integrate over all possible $r$s of

$$I_z = \iint\limits_{\Omega} r^2\ dm = \iint\limits_{\Omega} (x^2 + y^2)\ dm$$

where $\Omega$ is the laminar region (area).

[image]